# Javascript Thumbs up/down

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the following javascript, which is linked to a thumbs up and thumbs down button. When each is click the other turns off. This works perfectly. However the localstorage part doesn't

At the moment, when i refresh the page both buttons come 'on' (their active state colour)
I was trying to use removeItem so that when a button is pressed the localstorage for the other is forgotten and it won't show. However they both still come one.

Any ideas

**Updated;** Changed to ThumbStatus

```
function thumbsup(){

    document.getElementById("thumbsup").classList.remove("btn-default")
    document.getElementById("thumbsup").classList.add("btn-success")    
    document.getElementById("thumbsdown").classList.remove("btn-danger")
    document.getElementById("thumbsdown").classList.add("btn-default")

  localStorage.setItem('ThumbStatus',up);
  localStorage.removeItem('ThumbStatus', down);
  }



  function thumbsdown(){

    document.getElementById("thumbsdown").classList.remove("btn-default")
    document.getElementById("thumbsdown").classList.add("btn-danger")   
    document.getElementById("thumbsup").classList.remove("btn-success")
    document.getElementById("thumbsup").classList.add("btn-default")

  localStorage.setItem('ThumbStatus',down);
  localStorage.removeItem('ThumbStatus', up);
  }





function Loadthumbs1() {
   //if something was already saved....
  if ( localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus', up) ) 
  {
  var up = localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus', up);

   }


document.getElementById("thumbsup").classList.add("btn-success")

 }
function Loadthumbs2() {        
if ( localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus', down) ) {
var down = localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus', down);
}

document.getElementById("thumbsdown").classList.add("btn-danger")



}
```

Comment: you should use removeItem like localStorage.removeItem('LoadThumbsup');

Comment: I already have that in there.
localstorage.removeItem('loadThumbsUp', up);

Comment: You don't need the second `argument`.

Comment: Which argument are you referring to?

Comment: Try localstorage.removeItem('loadThumbsUp'); see http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-removeitem

Comment: I have used localstorage.removeItem('loadThumbsUp') but still both buttons are showing active

Comment: Instead of `LoadThumbsdown` and `LoadThumbsup` it might be easier to have something like `ThumbStatus` which can be set to either `up` or `down`. That way you don't have to remove anything from localStorage, just change the value.

Comment: @Andy Okay so i've changed it to thumbstatus. How would I go about changing the value and at what stage

Comment: Just a friendly recommendations to use jQuery instead of pure Javascript when it comes to working with DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tu = document.getElementById("thumbsup");
var td = document.getElementById("thumbsdown");
var thumbStatus = localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus');

function thumbsup() {
  tu.classList.remove("btn-default");
  tu.classList.add("btn-success");    
  td.classList.remove("btn-danger");
  td.classList.add("btn-default");
  localStorage.setItem('ThumbStatus', 'up');
 }

function thumbsdown() {
  td.classList.remove("btn-default");
  td.classList.add("btn-danger");   
  tu.classList.remove("btn-success");
  tu.classList.add("btn-default");
  localStorage.setItem('ThumbStatus', 'down');
 }

function Loadthumbs() {
  if (thumbStatus && thumbStatus === 'up' ) {
   thumbsup();
  }
  if (thumbStatus && thumbStatus === 'down' ) {
   thumbsdown();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just tried this but still no luck. Both buttons are showing active

Comment: The Loadthumbs1 and loadthumbs2 functions load that the end of the page

Comment: Perhaps `localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus', 'up')` not `localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus', up)`.

Comment: Still no joy. I think that would be setting it to two different keys anyway (one called thumbstatus and one called up)

Comment: Sorry, not thinking straight this morning. I've made a change to my answer.

Comment: This didn't work. in the bottom two load functions did you mean to put.    thumbStatus = localStorage.getItem('ThumbStatus, up');
for loadthumbs1 etc

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle or a gist of your code. I'm struggling to see what bits get called where.

Comment: I could, but i'm using bootstrap

Comment: the 'Loadthumbs1' and 'Loadthumbs2' get called at the very end of the code. (when page has loaded) and the 'thumbsup' and 'thumbsdown' function get called when a thumbs up or down button is pressed

Comment: Ah. How about this edit? One function gets called, and then calls thumbsup or thumbsdown depending on whether the status is up or down.

Comment: This is perfect! So i'm guessing it needed the ===

Comment: Yeah, it took me a moment to figure out what that getItem was trying to do. I've added some caching and a check for localStorage into my final edit.